# Returning values from Thymeleaf view

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I'm developing an app with Thymeleaf and Spring 4. I need to return a value since a select.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" th:action="@{/processInfoBook}"   th:object="${relationshipDTO}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<select style="visibility:hidden" hidden="hidden" class="form-control" th:field="*{typeTo}">
    <option th:each="book : ${session.Book}" th:value="${book.getClass().getSimpleName()}"></option>
</select>
```

With that approach the variable `String typeTo` in my controller is set, but with this, it isn't.

```
<input th:with="bookType=${session.Book[1]}" type="hidden" th:field="*{typeTo}" th:value="${bookType.getClass().getSimpleName()}" />
```

Can someone explain me what's happening here and how can I fix it, I would prefer use the second approach since I have another select, and I'm replicating the same code just to set another variable.

Thanks!

```
public class RelationshipDTO {

    private String typeFrom;
    private String typeTo;
    private String dataFrom;
    private String bookTo;
    ...setters and getters
```

}

And the view:

```
<input type="hidden" th:field="${relationshipDTO.dataFrom}" />
<input type="hidden" th:field="${relationshipDTO.typeFrom}" />
<div class="form-group">
<label for="anotherBook" class="col-sm-5 control-label">TO</label> 
<select class="form-control" th:field="${relationshipDTO.bookTo}">
    <option th:each="book : ${session.Book}" th:value="${book.name}" th:text="${book.name}"></option>
</select> 
//This is the null field
<input th:with="bookType=${session.Book[1]}" type="hidden" th:field="${relationshipDTO.typeTo('hola')}"/>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing concepts, if you say to thymeleaf that you will render the values from a form, and with a particular object, then you have to use the th:field attribute but th:value.

Also you had a typo in the tag

> th:with="bookType=${session.Book[1]}"

You were assigning to one request variable "bookType" inside the input.

Try with only this:

```
<input th:with="${session.Book[1]}" type="hidden" th:field="*{typeTo}"/>
```

I assume the attribute typeTo is into your object relationshipDTO.

Comment: I've tried with that, however my property is still null. How can Thymeleaf know which data I'm trying to send to the field typeTo?

Comment: If is a primitive or standard java object, spring will bind the value of your field to convert into String, Integer,...if is a custom object or an enum that you created for your business logic, you need to set id of your object or if is an enum the name of it. Please let me know your entity how looks like and i will try to give you a good example

Comment: Actually it isn't exaclty an entity. From a file I upload the elements to the session and I put them in lists.

Comment: Could you update your question with this entity? relationshipDTO

Comment: @sirandy Try the example now, and copy please also the for tag, i am confuse how you are using the th:field attribute

Comment: Nope, It throws this exception: Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as assignation sequence: "${session.Book[1]}" (infoBook:25).

Maybe I'm mixing needlessly all the things. The problem is that I need assign two fields since the <select> but this can't be done. Do you know another way to do it? 

I just want to return data about what user is selecting in the view. Maybe I'm complicating all the things.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110413/discussion-between-cralfaro-and-sirandy).

Comment: @sirandy share your email and i will try to explain one option by email to dont make it longer and confuse people here